# List divs in columns, expanding to parent width

Tags: html, css

I was looking for a way to list multiple divs and, if they can't fit, move them to a new line.
Some pictures might illustrate my needs better:

[image]

The height and width of divs (red boxes) are constant.

Bootstrap is not an option.

the boxes also have to be centered so when you start increasing the parent width, they should center themselves automatically without leaving a gap on the side.

Thanks for pointing me to a right direction.

Comment: ah good old stackoverflow haven't changed a bit, posting a new question and it starts generating downvotes right away.

Comment: Well, you're asking people to write code for you, for free, without you having to do anything more than make a few pictures.

Comment: I'm not asking to write the code. I'm just asking for a broad opinion on what css structure I should use.

Comment: I recommend doing a little research. Make an attempt or two, then let us know what you tried and what specifically goes wrong. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: And Stack Overflow is not a place for asking for broad opinions https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block`:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.boxWrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxWrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Also, see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/09d32pq9/) fiddle.

To center only the container, you could use `display: grid`:

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.boxWrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 250px);
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxWrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Or see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/u2rwzcpz/) fiddle.

However, this is not supported by IE. But I could not figure out a different way without using CSS Grid.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, though is there a way to make the last box float the left and not the center?

Comment: @Nedas So, if the last box is alone in the row, it should be aligned left and otherwise centered?

Comment: That is correct. Also there are cases when two boxes are the last ones, they should be aligned left aswell.

Comment: @Nedas Okay, see my update. I guess, this is what you mean.